# Getting NoSuchBeanException on migrating my application from Micronaut 2.2.0 to Micronaut 3.5.0

Tags: micronaut

I am migrating my application from Micronaut 2.2.0 to Micronaut 3.5.0 using the official [Micronaut documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/3.5.0/guide/index.html#upgrading)

One of the changes which i did was regarding the *Inject Annotation*.
It says that the javax.inject annotations are no longer a transitive dependency. Micronaut now ships with the Jakarta inject annotations. **Either replace all javax.inject imports with jakarta.inject, or add a dependency on javax-inject to continue using the older annotations:**

So we removed the javax inject dependency and replace the javax.inject imports with jakarta.inject. After rebuilding and compiling it, it throws us a compilation error of *javax.inject.Singleton* not found.

[image]

Note : Even after removing the javax dependency (also check the external libraries and didn't find any javax library there), the Singleton annotation is getting imported from javax.inject.Singleton.
So to resolve this we added the javax.inject and the compilation got completed successfully. But then we are getting the NoSuchBeanException for the injected classes in our Integration Tests.

[image]

In the exception the "clock" object has been injected with the @Inject annotation in the Controller class.

Anyone has any idea of what might be going wrong here.??

**After enabling the debug logging for the *'io.micronaut.context.condition'* package which will log the reasons why beans were not loaded, i get the following debug and error logs.**

```
2023-01-09 12:27:15.373 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: com.csg.pb.scot.entitlements.apis.$SimulationBreakfundAPIEntitlementIT$MockBreakfundCalculationServiceBean1$Definition$Intercepted] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
2023-01-09 12:27:15.373 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Custom condition [class io.micronaut.test.condition.TestActiveCondition] failed evaluation
2023-01-09 12:27:15.374 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: com.csg.pb.scot.entitlements.apis.$InceptionSimulationAPIEntitlementIT$MockInceptionCalculationServiceBean1$Definition$Intercepted] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
2023-01-09 12:27:15.374 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Custom condition [class io.micronaut.test.condition.TestActiveCondition] failed evaluation
2023-01-09 12:27:15.377 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: com.csg.pb.scot.entitlements.apis.InceptionSimulationAPIEntitlementIT] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
2023-01-09 12:27:15.377 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Custom condition [class io.micronaut.test.condition.TestActiveCondition] failed evaluation
2023-01-09 12:27:15.379 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: com.csg.pb.scot.entitlements.apis.SimulationBreakfundAPIEntitlementIT] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
2023-01-09 12:27:15.379 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Custom condition [class io.micronaut.test.condition.TestActiveCondition] failed evaluation
2023-01-09 12:27:15.532 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: com.csg.pb.scot.entitlements.apis.InceptionAPIEntitlementIT] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
2023-01-09 12:27:15.532 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Custom condition [class io.micronaut.test.condition.TestActiveCondition] failed evaluation
2023-01-09 12:27:15.539 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: com.csg.pb.scot.entitlements.apis.$InceptionAPIEntitlementIT$MockInceptionCalculationServiceBean1$Definition$Intercepted] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
2023-01-09 12:27:15.539 [io-executor-thread-2] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Custom condition [class io.micronaut.test.condition.TestActiveCondition] failed evaluation
2023-01-09 12:27:15.862 [io-executor-thread-1] ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Failed to inject value for parameter [responseMapper] of class: com.csg.pb.scot.calculation.engine.InceptionCalculationService
```

Comment: did you enable the logger `io.micronaut.context.condition` to `debug` to see what the framework reports? can you add the source of the missing bean?

Comment: I enabled it but it gave me some debug logs stating that "Bean will not be loaded because of custom condition failed evaluation".. You can check the logs in the appended question.

Comment: Ok, now you see that TestActiveCondition is the issue. Please debug it and check why the evaluation fails